# Windows File Sharing user checkbox uncheckable

Tags: macos, sharing, smb

I seem to be unable to complete the setup of sharing a folder via SMB.  I have turned on file sharing and have checked 'Share files and folders using SMB' but I cannot choose a user account under the section called Windows File Sharing:

> Sharing files with some Windows computers requires storing the user's
>   account password on this computer is a less secure manner.  When you
>   enable Windows sharing for a user account, you must enter the password
>   of that account.

[image: Windows File Sharing Mac]

I can see my computer on the network from another computer but I cannot access the file shares with this mac's username and password.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might help ... basically you need to create a "share-only" user on the Mac.

http://chriswrites.com/how-to-share-files-folders-between-the-mac-and-pc/

Comment: My main account wasn't showing up in the list either, possibly due to some niche restrictions (not full admin?). Creating a share-only account was exactly what I needed.